# How to wrap function with prefix and suffix in C

Tags: c, design-patterns

I'd like to know how to solve the wrapper problem from the
[Stroustrup paper](http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf) but in C. I'm trying to find an efficient way to call

```
// prefix
GenericFunctionCallThatCouldHaveAnyNumberOfArgs();
// suffix
```

I've thought about creating a proxy function that takes an input a function pointer but the functions I want to wrap do not all have the same function signature.

My current solution is to create a Macro:

```
#define CALL(func) prefix; func; suffix;
CALL(myfunction(a, 'b', 1))
```

It works but it makes the code harder to understand especially when the prefix and suffix are complicated. Also the prefix and suffix are not necessarily calls to functions, they can be enclosures too. Is there a design pattern in C that does this efficiently (in terms of lines of code) while still maintaining readability.

Answer (score 1):

For function calls of return type `void` you could use the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other), which - with some restrictions - allows to specify several expressions that are evaluated one after the other, including a function call.

For example, you could write

```
#define prefix printf("something in prefix\n")
#define suffix printf("something as suffix\n")
void someFunction(int x) {
    printf("some function, parameter value %d\n", x);
}

#define CALL(func) (prefix,func,suffix)

int main() {

    CALL(someFunction(10));
}
```

Output:

```
something in prefix
some function, parameter value 10
something as suffix
```

There are several restrictions on what can be an expression used within a comma operator. For example, you cannot define a variable in the course of such an expression. However, there are some strategies to overcome this, e.g. by introducing global variables or by calling functions (which may define local variables, of course).

The reason for return type `void` is that you want to call your function "in the middle", i.e. not as the last expression in the comma operator, but the result of the comma operator per is always the value to which the last expression evaluates. Note further that with the `#define CALL(func)`- approach any change in the `prefix` or in the `suffix` requires recompilation of your program. But I think you are aware of this anyway.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I've thought about creating a proxy function that takes an input a function pointer but the functions I want to wrap do not all have the same function signature.

This can be solved by adding another layer of indirection. It won't make the code any shorter, though.

Let's say we want to call two functions, `foo()` (passing no arguments) and `bar(42, "hello")` (two arguments of different types) with the same prefix/suffix code.

We can do it like this:

```
void call_decorated(void (*f)(void *), void *p) {
    printf("prefix code\n");
    f(p);
    printf("suffix code\n");
}
```

This lets us call any function that takes a single `void *` argument. To use this with `foo` and `bar`, we have to write adapter functions:

```
void wrap_foo(void *p) {
    foo();
}

struct bar_args {
    int n;
    const char *s;
};

void wrap_bar(void *p) {
    struct bar_args *args = p;
    bar(args->n, args->s);
}
```

Now we can call `call_decorated` like this:

```
call_decorated(wrap_foo, NULL);

struct bar_args args = { 42, "hello" };
call_decorated(wrap_bar, &args);
```

This gets very tedious, but there is only one instance of the prefix/suffix code in the source.

Comment: As pointed out in the paper this gets tedious because the designer must create a wrapper for each function. Which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Mozly In that case I think a macro is probably going to be your best bet.